# Having trouble proving the equation defines an implicit function in a neighbourhood of 0

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, implicit-function-theorem

I've just learned the implicit function theorem from my course, and I found that I have some trouble when doing the exercises, that I don't know how to actually apply the implicit function theorem.

Here is a simple example from my exercise sheet:

$\textbf(Exercise)$

Show that the equation $$xy^4 - x^3 +y = 0$$ defines an implicit function $\phi:x \to y$ in a neighbourhood of $0$ and that $\phi(0) = 0$.

My question is, first of all, I don't know where should I start the proof, and then what does neighborhood here mean?

I understand my question could be stupid, I searched for some similar questions on the Internet but the difference made me more confused.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: How was the implicit function theorem stated to you? It might help to connect the mental dots if we knew where you were starting from.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you very much for your answer, at the moment, I hope it's not wrong, what I understand is "Suppose p,q $\in$ N^*, an open set $\omega$ of $R ^(p+q)$ and $ F \in C^1(\omega , R^q)$ if $(x_0 , y_0) \in \omega$ such that $F(x_0 , y_0)=0$, if we can show $det(\frac[dF][dy])(x_0, y_0)$ is not equal to 0, then we can say the equation defines an implicit function?"